# Exoplayer 2.0 hls Response code: 505 error on some devices

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer

I am streaming Hls video in exoplayer link is working fine but the problem is video won't stream on certain devices.... logcat

```
Source error.
                                                                           com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 505
                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:211)
                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:123)
                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:251)
                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:200)
                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:295)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

the pattern I found is this error occurring on device below Android nougat

Answer (score 3):

Check your video link. It may not be properly encoded (contain spaces). I have got the same problem.

If the URL contains a space it will work on some devices, on others I got an 505 error.